# How create runnable .jar file in Intellij/Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

Can someone tell me how run .jar file with Intellij and Gradle in cmd?

I try create manifest file but get errors:

```
no main manifest attribute, in eureka-server.jar
```

or

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.project.EurekaServerApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.EurekaServerApplication
```

My main class:

```
package com.project;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

In MANIFEST.MF in path /resources/META-INF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.project.EurekaServerApplication
```

Also I try it, in build.gradle

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.project.EurekaServerApplication'
        )
    }
}
```

I run this jar file in this way:

```
java -jar [nameApplication].jar
```

Comment: This is `SpringBoot` application you should run it with `gradle bootRun` command not from a `.jar` file

Comment: Ok, but I need this jar  file then to create docker container and get the same error. This solution help me?

Comment: Do you want to know how to run .jar (question text) or how to create one (title)?

Comment: How create that run without error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the .jar file you have to make it executable after the gradle build (regardless of intellij), use the [bootRepackage task](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration) in your gradle file:

```
bootRepackage {
  mainClass = 'com.project.EurekaServerApplication'
}
```